# Raising Error not working in MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, raiseerror

I am trying to raise an error within my trigger if a person's lastname is not in full caps or if the first letter of their firstname is not in caps . But my code doesn't seem to raise an alarm if those scenarios are met. Can someone please explain to me how I can do so ?

**This is my table:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS people;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (
Id_People smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Firstname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Lastname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Birth     DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (Id_People)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1002 ;DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insert_people;
```

**This is my trigger**

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insert_people;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER insert_people BEFORE INSERT ON people
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    IF NOT  (NEW.Lastname like UCASE ) THEN 
          SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'the lastname must be in full caps ';
           
    ELSE IF
         NOT (NEW.Firstname like ucfirst ) THEN
           SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'the first letter of the firstname must be in caps'; 
    
     END IF; 
  END IF;
 
END$$
```

Comment: What are ucase and ucfirst?

Comment: ucase is UPPERCASE and ucfirst is The first letter in caps

Comment: And where are these defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code to find those is not correct.

Please add `DELIMITER` to the trigger code, as it isn't necessary in the example site

> ```
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS people;
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (
> Id_People smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
> Firstname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
> Lastname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
> Birth     DATE,
> PRIMARY KEY (Id_People)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1002 ;DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insert_people;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER insert_people BEFORE INSERT ON people
> FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
>     IF NOT  (NEW.Lastname=BINARY UPPER(NEW.Lastname)) THEN 
>           SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
>             SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'the lastname must be in full caps ';
>            
>     ELSE IF
>          NOT (ASCII(NEW.Firstname) BETWEEN 65 AND 90 ) THEN
>            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
>             SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'the first letter of the firstname must be in caps'; 
>     
>      END IF; 
>   END IF;
>  
> END
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO people VALUES (NULL,'Hallo','Kitty','1980-01-01')
> ```
>
> ```
> the lastname must be in full caps
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO people VALUES (NULL,'hallo','KITTY','1980-01-01')
> ```
>
> ```
> the first letter of the firstname must be in caps
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab9dd801973212164077ea1e3b43e1b5)*